# Error: Importing Data CSV Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm very new to the concept of importing data into a SQL database with CSV. I've followed some stackoverflow posts but I'm getting an error. The error states, **`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - products.csv`** after running `rake import:data`. I have csv required in my application.rb as well as I have created a csv file and placed it in TMP. Here is my code so far.
 I understand I may be asking for a lot from the community but if someone were to answer this question, can you provide some more insight into CSV and rake functions. Thanks so much!!!

```
<b>import.rake</b>
    namespace :import do 
        desc "imports data from a csv file"
        task :data => :environment do
            require 'csv'
            CSV.foreach('tmp/products.csv') do |row|
                name = row[0]
                price = row[1].to_i
                Product.create( name: name, price: price )
            end

        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path to the CSV file.

For example, if the file is in `/tmp/` use:

```
CSV.foreach('/tmp/products.csv') do |row|
```

If the `products.csv` file is in your application's `tmp` directory use:

```
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'products.csv')) do |row|
```

Comment: When I add the CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'products.csv')) do |row| The error goes away but I receive another error NameError: uninitialized constant Product? What can i do to fix this one?

Comment: Your Product model is not being found. You're already loading the Rails environment, so do you have a Product model defined?

Comment: I have a product.rb but I dont have any methods defined. What am I missing. Sorry if I'm asking rudimentary questions

Comment: It might be helpful to add your Product model to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar, it was forgetting to put both parenthesis with the braces so you might want to try going from:

```
Product.create( name: name, price: price )
```

to:

```
Product.create({ name: name, price: price })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) Gem.

In it's simplest form you can do this:

```
      SmarterCSV.process('tmp/products.csv').each do |hash|
        Product.create( hash )
      end
```

Add smarter_csv to your Gemfile, so it's auto-loaded when you require the environment in your Rake task

This gives you:

```
     namespace :import do
       desc 'imports data from given csv file'
       task :data, [:filename] => :environment do |t, args|
         fail "File not found" unless File.exists? args[:filename]

         options = {} # add options if needed
         SmarterCSV.process( args[:filename], options).each do |hash|
           Product.create( hash )
         end
       end
     end
```

Call it like this:

```
      rake import:data['/tmp/products.csv']
```

See also: https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv